# MobileFirst 7.1 and Collecting Analytics for Network Connections to other servers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I try to collect analytics information for network connections outside MFP Server.

MFP 7.1.0.00.20151005-1721

For this test case, i use the following sample:  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/

and replace in the source code :

var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/RSSReader/getFeedFiltered", WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['MobileFirst_Platform']");
    resourceRequest.send().then(
            loadFeedsSuccess,
            loadFeedsFailure, ...

by

var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml", WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.send().then(
            loadFeedsSuccess,
            loadFeedsFailure, ...

And add in the loadFeedsSucess function a line with WL.Analytics.send()

The request works fine but no data available in MobileFirst Analytic Console for Network (Session and device are OK)

[image: Sessions view]
[image: Network view]

How to show other request metrics in Network view ?

Thanks

Fred.

Comment: Did you found something about this, I am facing similar issue and not able to see any networking related information on Analytics console. Even I am able to get below logs 
[WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:344 :: Request Success

[WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:345 :: Response Status Code : 200

Answer (score 0):

The metrics under the network tab are going to be populated when you use adapters. These metrics on network request are not populated when using third party servers.

If you create an adapter to hit the engadget rss feed then you will start to collect metrics from your adapter.

Comment: In the IBM Knowledge Center MFP 7.1 you can read the following : "To enable collection of network analytics to servers other than the MobileFirst Server, use WLResourceRequest provided in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation. This API exists for native iOS, native Android, and hybrid applications." So, it is possible to collect metrics from adapter but from other ressources too. But how to see it in analytic console ?

Comment: Hi Freddut. I was a bit wrong. I will edit my answer. I am seeing Round trip and average request size under 'Network Summary'. Try calling WL.Logger.send() or WL.Analytics.send() after the call finishes. Even after the promise. I do not think the data has been written to the file by the point you are sending. Also make sure you are checking the 'Network Summary' tab and not the adapter summary. 'Adapter Summary' is only going to populate with adapters.